# How are race/class combinations unlocked in Mass Effect 3 multiplayer?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

[This ME3 wiki page](http://masseffect.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Effect_3_Multiplayer/Character_Customization#Powers) has a list of possible race/class combinations, but by default only the human options are available. **How are the other races unlocked?**

Comment: I would suggest reserving questions about what does or does not need to be unlocked until the actual games come out and we know that those options need unlocking.

Comment: Updated the question to be more specific to the demo, hopefully that helps.

Comment: @murgatroid99 this question is fine as is - the multiplayer demo is *the actual game*, just character level and match-type capped. It might be *easier* to answer in a week, but it *can* be authoritatively answered now.

Comment: @RavenDreamer yeah, I think it looks fine now. The original version seemed to be asking a question about the actual game based on the structure of the demo, which seemed premature.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This might require updating after the game releases, but in the demo, you can get additional race/class unlocks by purchasing "item packs" with credits you earn by playing the game.

In the demo version, there's a "Recruit Pack" that costs 5,000 cr, and a "Veteran Pack" that costs 20,000 cr.  Think of these like a pack of cards you might buy for a collectible card game - you'll get a random assortment of several different things, including the possibility of unlocking a new character.

Comment: Last character I unlocked was the Asari Adept, who was a Gold bordered card - so new character classes look like they're pretty rare.

Comment: Note that the Vet packs, whilst costing more, do (ostensibly) give you a higher chance of getting "rare" unlocks, which all of the alien versions I've seen have been.

Comment: Wow, the CCG analogy is a pretty good one.

Comment: Some class unlocks are "uncommon" others are "rare" -- and if you get a double, you receive an XP boost instead and the option to modify the appearance further.