# Does multiplayer level transfer between races for each class?

Tags: mass-effect-3, mass-effect-3-multiplayer

From the answer to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52828/16793) question, we know that multiplayer races are unlocked by purchasing item packs in the in-game store. **If I have a level 10 human infiltrator and unlock the ability to create a salarian infiltrator, will my level be preserved when I switch to the salarian, or do both versions of the class level up independently?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Every *class* shares a level; it is not split between individual soldiers.

This means, every time you unlock a new class, race, or gender, you're only starting from level 1 if you've never played as them before.

Comment: I just read in the Giant Bomb review (http://www.giantbomb.com/mass-effect-3/61-29935/reviews/ - fourth paragraph from the bottom) that all of the races for a class level up together.  Is it possible that they changed this from the demo or is Giant Bomb out to lunch on this one?

Comment: @BrysonDuda You're right! Good catch.

Comment: In the PC Demo all the races in a class leveled up together. Did it not work that way in the demos for other platforms?